# How to get report solutions from SQL Server Reporting Services?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, solution

How can one extract report solutions from SQL Server Reporting Services?

I may need to take over development of reports, but original solutions are... missing.

What can be done in such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible. It depends on how many reports you have, but if you edit the properties of a report in the reporting services manager web site you can choose to download the rdl file, just add those to a new solution in visual studio.
Have a look at [this link](http://sql-articles.com/articles/general/download-export-rdl-files-from-report-server/)

There are automated ways to get all rdl files if you want that too.

There is a SQL only way [for example](http://www.sql-server-citation.com/2013/08/ssrs-download-all-rdl-files-from-report.html).

The easiest way in my opinion is using the [RS.exe command line interface](http://blog.geektrainer.com/2012/04/download-all-reports.html)